# Slow promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm fairly new to node.js and Promises in general, although I think I get the gist of how they are supposed to work (I've been forced to use ES5 for a looooong time). I also have little in-depth knowledge of Cloud Functions (GCF), though again I do understand at a high level how they work

I'm using GCF for part of my app, which is meant to receive a HTTP request, translate them and send them onward to another endpoint. I need to use promises, as there are occasions when the originating HTTP request has multiple 'messages' sent at once

So, my function works in regards to making sure messages are sent in the correct order, but the subsequent messages are sent on very slowly (the logs suggest it's around a 20 second difference in terms of actually being sent onward)

I'm not entirely sure why that is happening - I would've expected it to be less than a couple of seconds difference. Maybe it's something to do with GCF and not my code? Or maybe it is my code? Either way, I'd like to know if there's something I can do to speed it up, especially since it's supposed to send it onward to a user in Google chat

(Before anyone comments on why it's request.body.body, I don't have control over the format of the incoming request)

```js
exports.onward = (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send();

    let bodyArr = request.body.body;

    //Chain Promises over multiple messages sent at once stored in bodyArr
    bodyArr.reduce(async(previous, next) =>{
        await previous;
        return process(next);
    }, Promise.resolve());
};

function process(body){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Obtain JWT from Google
        let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
            privatekey.client_email,
            null,
            privatekey.private_key,
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']
        );
        
        //Authorise JWT, reject promise or continue as appropriate
        jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
            if(err){
                console.error('Google OAuth failure ' + err);
                reject();
            }else{
                let payload = copyPayload();
                setValues(payload, body); //Other function which sets payload values

                axios.post(url, payload,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokens.access_token
                        },
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        //HTTP 2xx response received
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        switch(true){
                        //Something bad happened
                        reject();
                    });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT: After testing the same thing, it's gone done a bit to around a 3-6 second delay between promises. Given that the code didn't change, I suspect that it's something to do with GCF?

Answer (score 2):

By doing

```
exports.onward = (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send();

    let bodyArr = request.body.body;

    // Any work
};
```

you are incorrectly managing the life cycle of your Cloud Function: As a matter of fact by doing `response.status(200).send();` you are indicating to the Cloud Functions platform that your function successfully reached its terminating condition or state and that, consequently, the platform can shut it down. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc for more explanations.

Since you send this signal **at the beginning** of your Cloud Function it may happen that the Cloud Functions shuts it down before the asynchronous job is finished.

In addition, you are potentially generating some "erratic" behavior of the Cloud Function that makes it difficult to debug. Sometimes your Cloud Function is terminated before the asynchronous work is completed, for the reason explained above. But some other times, the Cloud Function platform does not terminate the Function immediately and the asynchronous work can be completed (i.e. has the possibility to complete before the Cloud Function is terminated).

So, you should send the response **after all the work is completed**.

---

If you want to immediately acknowledged the user that the work has been started, without waiting for this work to be completed, you should use [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/): in your main Cloud Function, delegate the work to a [Pub/Sub triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) and then return the response.

If you want to acknowledge the user when the work is completed (i.e. when the Pub/Sub triggered Cloud Function is completed), there are several options: Send a notification, an email or write to a Firestore document that you watch from your app.